# Error: Edge undeclared (first use in the function)

Tags: c, debugging

I'm having the error that is in the title. I don't really get where it's coming from but the error is located in line 26 of the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Uma estrutura para representar um arco pesado no grafo.
struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};

// Uma estrutura para representar um grafo ligado, não dirigido e pesado.
struct Graph {
    // V -> Número de vértices (Número de cidades), E -> Número de arcos (Número de estradas + conecções por aeroportos).
    int V;
    int E;

    // O grafo é representado como um array de arcos.
    // Visto o grafo ser não dirigido, o arco
    // da origem (src) ao destino (dest) é igual
    // ao arco de dest a src. Ambos são contados como 1 arco.
    struct Edge *edge;
};

// Cria um grafo com V vértices e E arcos.
struct Graph *createGraph(int V, int E) {
    struct Graph *graph;
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = Edge[E];

    return graph;
};
```

Comment: Is that an [mcve]? I don't see an array named Edge anywhere in what you posted.

Comment: I tried to name an Array called Edge but it still kept giving me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: the "Edge" in line 26 is undeclared, just as it sais:

`graph->edge = Edge[E];`

Edge is a type in your code, so Edge[E] does not really make sense. You would use the [] indexing operator on arrays, so that is definitely a problem there.

I guess I know what you wanted to do there, you wanted to create an array of Edge types. Try it like this:

`graph->edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(struct Edge));`

Since you have a pointer in graph, you need to allocate the memory for that. But don't forget to delete it at the end.

`free(graph->edge);`

Or else you will get a memory leak.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};

struct Graph {
    int V;
    int E;
    struct Edge* edge;
};

struct Graph* createGraph(int V, int E) {
    struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->V = V;
    graph->E = E;
    graph->edge = (struct Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(struct Edge));
    return graph;
};
```

Comment: Maybe write a `void destroyGraph()` function where you call `free`. And call this function when you don't need the graph anymore.

Comment: After addind (graph->edge = new Edge[E];), it's giving me 2 errors:
   -'new' undeclared (first use in function);
   -expecter ';' before 'Edge'.
Both are in line 29.

Comment: Yes I edited my answer since that. I wrote "new", that is the same as "malloc" but in C++. So look at my answer again. I edited it to use malloc instead for C, I am sorry.

Comment: Okay, the error "Edge undeclared (first use in this function)" persists but at least one of the errors changed. It changed to "expected expression before ')' token"

Comment: Copy here that line again, how it looks now, please.

Comment: graph->edge = (Edge*)malloc(E * sizeof(Edge));

Comment: I edited it again, please try with that again.

Comment: struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));

Comment: You create a temporary variable there and then you return the address of it. That will lead to segfault. That needs to be allocated dynamically as well.

Comment: So take a look at the edited reply, it works by me, but write here if it does not work for you. Now remember, that you made dynamic memory allocation, first for graph, then for edge. So you will need to FIRST free edge, THEN free graph when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: It is preferable to use `calloc()` for the `Edge` array so it is initialized to all bits zero. Testing for allocation failure is advisable too.

Comment: I agree with the testing, you should always test whether the return of malloc is `NULL` (failed) or not. Whether `calloc()` is preferable or not, that depends on the application. If you need them to be set to 0, then sure, also if you are not the user, then it is safer, but it is not generally preferable over `malloc`, only in certain situations.

Comment: If this answered your question, could you please accept it as answer?